# How to create Cmder shortcut to start a task

Tags: shortcuts, cmder

I created a simple task that will start the Linux subsystem, execute zsh and run it on my desktop. However I would like to create a shortcut for this specific task on my taskbar.

Reason for this is because I don't want Cmder to do that by default, I want two separate buttons - one for regular and other for Ubuntu Subsystem.

Any ideas of how to do that? I've tried `"C:\Program Files\Cmder\Cmder.exe" /single /cmd {Bash:Ubuntu}` but it gives error `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` and loads default Cmder task.

Here is how my task looks like [image: task]

Answer (score 10):

Here are two options:

You can set cmder to show your tasks on the windows taskbar. In the settings check under `Task bar` > `Add ComEmu tasks to taskbar` and be sure to hit `Update now!`

If you still want to create the shortcut, this command seems to do the trick:

```
"C:\Program Files\Cmder\vendor\conemu-maximus5\ConEmu64.exe" -run {Task}
```

Use ConEmu64.exe or ConEmu.exe (accordingly) inside your `vendor\conemu-maximus5` folder of your cmder installation.

Answer (score 2):

The first option of previous answer, now changes to `Settings - Tasks - Taskbar jump lists(checkbox)` I guess? Because I don't see what he said, may be changed now; and then when you open the first shell, at right lower corner, click the green `+` sign, you will see your favorite task in the task list, at bottom.

When I use the second approach of @archemiro I see this error:

```
Unrecognized parameter:

Valid options:
/START <path>
/SINGLE <path>
/TASK <name>
/REGISTER [USER/ALL]
/UNREGISTER [USER/ALL]
```

Must have suffered some change during the updates of Cmder.

So I tried editing the shortcut path to be like `C:\xxxx\Cmder.exe /TASK my_task` and it worked. Remember that in `my_task`, no `{}` is included.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/a/1270844/1900291

`Cmder.exe` switches are different than `Conemu.exe` switches the `/TASK` is a Cmder switch for some reason `cmder.exe /TASK <task_name>` throws incorrect command   error for me but `Conemu.exe -run {task_name}` runs ok!

edit: add backticks format

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241302)